# PHP Add Column Data to Table IF Condition True

Tags: php, html, foreach, file-exists

This is a tough one. I'm not sure how to explain this but I'll try my best. I have a table where all values are coming from DB based on a search form:

[image: table]

The last column "Map Link" appears if a certain condition is true:

```php
$path = 'C:/my/path/here/maps/';

$find_ein = array_column($data, 'ein');
                    
foreach($find_ein as $map_ein){
    $map = $path.$map_ein.'_integration_map.xlsx';
    if(file_exists($map)){
        echo '<th class="report-headings">Map Link</th>';
        $map_link = $map;
    }else{
        //echo "no";
    }
}
```

I'm trying to echo `$map_link` into this column. In this example, `$map_link` only belongs to the 2nd row because not all EIN's have a map link. For the ones that do, the EIN # is included in the file name which is why I check for `if(file_exists)`. `$map_link` is instead getting added to each column: (you can barely see but at top of table, I echo `$map_link` to show what I am getting back, so there should only be 1 value going into Map Link column):
[image: table2]

```php
foreach ($data as $entry){
    // create a new row in the table
    echo '<tr style="text-align:center;line-height:32px;">';

    $count = count($entry);
    $y = 0;
    while ($y < $count){
        $current_row = current($entry);
        // then fill the columns
        echo '<td>'.$current_row.'</td><td><button><a href="'.$map_link.'">Map Link</a></button></td>';
                                
        next($entry);
        $y = $y + 1;
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

I don't know if any of this makes sense however this is the smartest community I have found out there, so I am hopeful someone might be able to help! Also I am very, very new.

Comment: It looks like `$entry` is your full row with 5 columns. If that is the case, then this code will echo 5 `<td>`s with a map link. If you only want the map link once, at the end, move that to its own `echo` after your `while` loop, right before your echo the `</tr>`.

Comment: @rickdenhaan fantastic! Of course the one place I did not test my echo statement. So now the Map Link button appears in the Map Link column, now I need to figure out how to only make it show up with its corresponding EIN. Any ideas on where to start?

Comment: I'd personally skip the first loop entirely, since the `$map_ein` you have there is available in this one as `$entry['ein']`. If you check for the file in this second loop, you know you're looking at the `$map_link` that belongs to this `$entry`.